# multiple candidate objects through ObjectInputStream in java

Tags: java, objectinputstream

I'm using ObjectInputStream with tcp sockets to retrieve and send serializable objects which are the core semantics of my program . But in order to cast them to objects , first I need to check one by one with instanceof to see if they are one currently defined classes. The problem is that i might end up needing many more of these classes. I know there is no great way to scan all subclasses, but can I make use of serializable interface somehow to reconstruct the object.

shorty here is what i mean

```
MyObj implements Serializable
....
SubClass1OfMyObj extends MyObj
Subclass2OfMyObj extends MyObj
Subclass3OfMyObj extends MyObj 
....
MyObj request = (MyObj)in.readObject();
if( request instanceof Subclass1OfMyObj)
if( request instanceof Subclass2OfMyObj)
if( request instanceof Subclass3OfMyObj)
....
```

edit: i need to be able to instantiate the correct subclass here. Like new Subclass1OfMyObj (...) things like that

As you can see, it is not very reusable to do this way, writing something like this in multiple places.

Comment: Your question is confusing here. After in.readObject(), if the deserialization succeeds, the "request" is aldready of the correct class. What further steps may you want to process  ?(the "things like that")

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how exactly you are deserializing this but, could you simply use the `getClass` method and pass it to some sort of factory?